# MySQL Query multiple year values

Tags: mysql

I build one search filter, in that filter users can filter using different fields of years, where they can select all or only specific years, and sort with different values. I will like to know how to run this Query in MySQL database.

what i am trying to achieve is :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  WHERE year LIKE 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
  ORDER BY parent DESC, student ASC, audience DESC
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE year IN (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
ORDER BY parent DESC, student ASC, audience DESC
```

Comment: Consistency in syntax, please :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can group a number of options using parenthesis and the `IN` operator.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table`
  WHERE year IN ( '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12' )
  ORDER BY parent DESC, student ASC, audience DESC
```

Comment: @triclosan just part of my coding style. don't know, if it has any benefits.

Comment: it hasn't! Moreover you force unnecessary type conversion by such qury.